# Problem on HDLBits: Exams/m2014 q6c, stuck at gnd

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Problem : https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Exams/m2014_q6c

Here is my code

```
module top_module (
    input [6:1] y,
    input w,
    output Y2,
    output Y4);

    parameter A = 000001, B = 000010, C = 000100, D = 001000, 
    E = 010000, F = 100000;
    reg [2:0] next_state;
    
    always @(*) begin
        casez(y)
        6'b000001 : next_state <= w ? A : B;
        6'b00001z : next_state <= w ? D : C;
        6'b0001zz : next_state <= w ? D : E;
        6'b001zzz : next_state <= w ? A : F;
        6'b01zzzz : next_state <= w ? D : E;
        6'b1zzzzz : next_state <= w ? D : C;
        default : next_state <= A;
        endcase
    end

    assign Y2 = next_state == B;
    assign Y4 = next_state == D;
endmodule
```

I can't understand why this code can't solve the problem. Using this code, Y2 and Y4 are stuck at GND.  I think there's a problem with "casez", but I am not sure.

Could you give me a correct answer and tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major bugs in your code.  When I run the simulation of your code on HDLBits, I see many warning messages which directly point to the problems, specifically, the ones under the heading: "Warning messages that may be important".

The 1st problem is that the state parameter values are decimal format, not binary format.  You need to add the `6'b` prefix to all the values:

```
parameter A = 6'b000001, B = 6'b000010, C = 6'b000100, D = 6'b001000, 
    E = 6'b010000, F = 6'b100000;
```

The 2nd problem is the width of the `next_state` signal.  It is only 3 bits wide, but it must be 6 bits wide in order to assign a 6-bit value to it.  Use:

```
reg [5:0] next_state;
```

These changes fix the problem mentioned in the question: Y2 and Y4 are no longer stuck at GND.  The changes also eliminate all warning messages.

---

Going forward, you really need to create your own [testbench](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20073232/197758) to debug further problems.  Unfortunately, the HDLBits online interface to the exercises like the one in the question does not allow you to see waveforms of *internal* signals.