# Why I cannot read and update the register array at the same time in clocked always block with non-blocking statements? (Conwaylife example)

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog

I am doing the Conwaylife question on HDLBits (link: https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Conwaylife). The question is kind of like a finite state machine, in which I need to update the output with the values calculated from the current output.

From the previous examples on Rule90 and Rule110 (also on the HDLBits), I intuitively wrote the update statement and the read statement of the output register `q` together in a clocked `always` block. Code is attached below:

```
module top_module(
    input clk,
    input load,
    input [255:0] data,
    output [255:0] q ); 
    
    reg [3:0] neighbor_cnt;
    reg [3:0] a, b, c, d;
    reg [7:0] N;
    
    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        if (load) q <= data;
        else begin
            for (int i=0; i<16; i++) begin:row
                for (int j=0; j<16; j++) begin:column
                    a <= i-1;
                    b <= i+1;
                    c <= j-1;
                    d <= j+1;  //overflow handling, wrap around naturally

                    N <= {q[a*16+c], q[a*16+d], q[b*16+c], q[b*16+d], q[i*16+c], q[i*16+d], q[a*16+j], q[b*16+j]};
                    neighbor_cnt <= N[0]+N[1]+N[2]+N[3]+N[4]+N[5]+N[6]+N[7];
                    case (neighbor_cnt)
                        2: q[i*16 + j] <= q[i*16 + j];
                        3: q[i*16 + j] <= 1;
                        default: q[i*16 + j] <= 0;
                    endcase
                end
            end
        end
    end

endmodule
```

The output is wrong - the simulation result of `q` becomes all 0 at cycle 2 (cycle 1 is reading input).

[image]

After some debugging (e.g. just run one cycle and write the middle variables like N and neighbor_cnt into q), I think my q is somehow not synchronous. It is updated too early or too late, as of which I cannot tell. Then I tried to convert all statements into blocking ones (I know it is not appropriate using blocking statements in clocked always, but just trying). The result shows that the `q` is delayed (the output that is supposed to be cycle 2 shows up at cycle 3, and messed up the following calculation).

Only after some research into others attempts on this question, I wrote a code that runs successfully:

```
module top_module(
    input clk,
    input load,
    input [255:0] data,
    output [255:0] q ); 
    
    reg [3:0] neighbor_cnt;
    reg [3:0] a, b, c, d;
    reg [7:0] N;
    wire [255:0] q_next;
    
    always @ (*) begin 
        for (int i=0; i<16; i++) begin:row
            for (int j=0; j<16; j++) begin:column
                a = i-1;
                b = i+1;
                c = j-1;
                d = j+1;  //overflow handling, wrap around naturally

                N = {q[a*16+c], q[a*16+d], q[b*16+c], q[b*16+d], q[i*16+c], q[i*16+d], q[a*16+j], q[b*16+j]};
                neighbor_cnt = N[0]+N[1]+N[2]+N[3]+N[4]+N[5]+N[6]+N[7];
                case (neighbor_cnt)
                    2: q_next[i*16 + j] = q[i*16 + j];
                    3: q_next[i*16 + j] = 1;
                    default: q_next[i*16 + j] = 0;
                endcase
            end
        end
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (load) q <= data;
        else q <= q_next;
    end

endmodule
```

The difference here is I used an intermediate `wire` `q_next` (not register), and place all calculations in a combinational `always` with blocking statements. But, I am still confused about why this difference could result in a successful code. If anyone can help out, I deeply appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is updated too early or too late, as of which I cannot tell.

The HDLBits interface is fine for very simple Verilog code, but it is inadequate for code like yours:

- You have no control over how you drive inputs
- You have limited visibility, with just whatever text output you are provided and maybe minimal waveforms
- It does have limited access to run your own simulation with `iverilog`, but it is too cumbersome, and the site recommends you use your own simulator
- The tool does not make its testbench code available to you

To debug your issue, you need to:

- Use another simulator
- [Create Verilog testbench code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073029/can-anyone-help-me-to-create-a-verilog-testbench)
- Run a simulation, dumping waveforms, like VCD
- View waveforms of internal signals to see the timing of the data signal to see if it is too early or too late

---

The HDLBits simulator is too forgiving.  Every other simulator I try your 1st code example on generates compile errors because `q` must be declared as a `reg`.  One way to do it is:

```
output reg [255:0] q );
```

Or, it can be declared on a separate line:

```
output [255:0] q ); 

reg [255:0] q;
```

You can see this on multiple simulators on EDA Playground.  The same is true for your 2nd code example.